# How pick up checkbox result in post method angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

I have a table that sets out a list of rules. When the checkboxes are clicked, I need them to take this "true" value and post to an API endpoint. This has been set up, but what I am getting back is that "associated_rule" is undefined.

I have tried setting `$scope.associated_rule.selected = true;` in my controller, but this still doesn't define the variable and throws up the same error in the console.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form name="rules_form" method="post" ng-submit="attach()">
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover" ng-model="associated_rules">
  <thead>
   <th>Rule Types:</th>
   <th>Description:</th>
   <th>Start Time:</th>
   <th>End Time:</th>
   <th>Apply Rule to Vehicle:</th>
  </thead>
 <tr ng-repeat="associated_rule in associated_rules">
 <td>@{{ associated_rule.resource_ids.accounts }}</td>
 <td>@{{ associated_rule.description }}</td>
 <td>@{{ associated_rule.start_time }}</td>
 <td>@{{ associated_rule.end_time }}</td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="associated_rule.selected" aria-label="rule"></td>
 </tr>
  </table>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="attach()">Attach</button>
 </form>
```

My Controller event:

```
$scope.attach = function () {
        $scope.associated_rule.selected = true;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.associated_rule.selected.length; i++) {
            //need to create a loop where the true value is picked up and then I can send the data using a POST method. But I'm stuck on this. 
        }
        console.log(the result of the event);
    };
```

For now, I just want the results to console.log, so I can see that the event is creating the loop and displaying the results. After that, I should be OK.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by defining the $scope.rule as an empty array and setting the $scope.rule.selected to "false" by default.

Great! step one! But the checkboxes are ALL selecting when you click A checkbox - think this may be the ng-repeat causing me a pain in the backside.

```
$scope.rule = [];
    $scope.rule.selected = false;
```

So, how do I ensure that only the checkboxes set that I select and not all at once?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this too; as the above was just making the entire array selected; as i wasn't drilling down into the array. This did it:

```
ng-model="rules.selected[associated_rule.id]"
```

by modelling the a rule within that defined array, it shows up when testing. Brill. :)

Answer (score 0):

By mistake you are changing the value of your check box on clicking the button:

```
$scope.associated_rule.selected = true;
```

This will give the current value, selected or not selected

```
 $log.log($scope.associated_rule.selected);
```